# React js how add "button value" after click to textarea

Tags: reactjs

I created a page with textarea.
I created desktop keyboard too.
I want to add a character after a click on it (this keyboard) to textarea.
How can I do this in React?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks this example

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea value={textValue} />
      <div className="buttons-box">
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}A`)}>A</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}B`)}>B</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}C`)}>C</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}D`)}>D</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}E`)}>E</button>
        <button onClick={() => setTextValue("")}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit recursing-sara-kf5jf]

Dynamic characters render

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);

  const getElements = () => {
    return [
      { label: "A", value: "A" },
      { label: "B", value: "B" },
      { label: "C", value: "C" },
      { label: "D", value: "D" },
      { label: "E", value: "E" }
    ];
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setElements([...getElements()]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <textarea value={textValue} readOnly />
      <div className="buttons-box">
        {elements && elements.length > 0 ? (
          elements.map((el) => (
            <button
              key={el.value}
              onClick={() => setTextValue(`${textValue}${el.label}`)}
            >
              {el.label}
            </button>
          ))
        ) : (
          <h6>No elemnts to show</h6>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is important:

- getElements could be a function to fetch content from an external API.
- setElements when the component has been mounted.
- guarantee the elements array has label and value prop and the value will always a unique value because it is used as a key for the buttons.

Comment: Thx it is OK :) but I have array with more than 50 elements and I don't want to create so many lines of code, is it posible to do this ?

Comment: and how to don't clear textarea? I want to add characters.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, let me do an example for you!

Comment: Can we make the text area editable as well? Like I can edit the textarea and use this as virtual keyboard or something?

Comment: Yes you can add the onChange event to de textArea and call the setTextValue function